# Different results using RDD and DataFrames

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I was creating word count of a text file using Spark RDD and DataFrame but the answers are slightly different. The data I am using is available [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2800/2800.txt).
Why are the answers different?

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, trim, lower, regexp_replace, explode, split, length
 from pyspark.sql import Row

 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 stopwords = stopwords.words('english')
```

### DataFrame

```
def clean1(line):
   return trim(lower(regexp_replace(line, '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','')))

 df1 = (spark.read.text("Quran.txt")
   .select(clean1('value').alias('line'))
   .select(explode(split('line', ' ')).alias('word'))
   .filter(length(col("word")) > 0)
   .filter(~col('word').isin(stopwords))
   .groupBy('word').count()
   .orderBy('count', ascending = False)
  )

  df1.show(10)
```

[image]

### RDD

```
 import re

 def cleanline(line):
    return re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]', '', line).lower().strip()

df2 = (sc.textFile('Quran.txt')
   .map(lambda x: cleanline(x))
   .flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))
   .filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0)
   .filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords)
   .map(lambda x: (x, 1))
   .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
   .sortBy(lambda x: -x[1])
   .map(lambda x: Row(word = x[0], count = x[1]))
   .toDF()
   .select(['word','count'])
  )

  df2.show(10)
```

[image]

### UPdate

I found out that if I change the regular expression in the DataFrame section from '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]' to '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]', the answers become the same. Are these two regular expression patterns not the same?

Comment: `\s` includes all whitespacing, not just spaces, so not quite the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the function definition of `trim`

```
'ltrim': 'Trim the spaces from left end for the specified string value.',
'rtrim': 'Trim the spaces from right end for the specified string value.',
'trim': 'Trim the spaces from both ends for the specified string column.',
```

which says that **trim removes only *spaces* and not *tabs (\t)***. but there are *tabs* in some of the lines as below which is not removed by `trim` function.

```
God could destroy him if He chose, v. 19 (488)
```

**Thats the reason `god` in the above line is not counted as there is tab in front of it. While the `strip`() function removed all the spaces including tabs in the front.**

Similar is the case for other counts as well.

So defining a `udf` function where `strip`() *python function* can be used is your solution.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def stripUdf(x):
    return x.strip()

callStripUdf = F.udf(stripUdf, T.StringType())

def clean1(line):
    return callStripUdf(F.trim(F.lower(F.regexp_replace(line, '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]',''))))
```

Now as you mentioned, changing from `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]` to `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` solved the issue, thats because *\s* means all the *whitespaces* including *tab(\t)* so the change replaced *tabs* to *empty* character before `trim` is applied.

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Thanks. (1) why did  not trim remove it ? (2) why does changing  '[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]' to '[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]' give correct result?

Comment: Sorry. I did not get you. if I use \s in the regular expression, should not that remove it before trim is applied to it?

Comment: you have used negation character `^` which means that what ever is inside `[]` won't get replaced.